# Error while running python scripts/diff_drive.py --remote http://10.100.82.30 --config=diff_vehicle

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Code snippet after running the `$python scripts/diff_drive.py --remote http://10.100.82.30 --config=diff_vehicle`

```
Detected running on rasberrypi. Only importing select modules.

Using TensorFlow backend.

Usage:

    drive.py [--remote=<name>] [--config=<name>]

Options:
  --remote=<name>   recording session name

  --config=<name>   vehicle configuration file name (without extension)  

[default: diff_vehicle]
```

I'm trying to build a differential Donkey Car. Using a Raspberry Pi3, Picam, and an ADAFRUIT Motor HAT for DC and Stepper motors.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Formatted and indented code.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "=" in one of the argument. python getopt accepts values in name=value form

Try
`$python scripts/diff_drive.py --remote=http://10.100.82.30 --config=diff_vehicle`

Comment: I performed the change and this was the change:

Detected running on rasberrypi. Only importing select modules.
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/diff_drive.py", line 25, in <module>
    cfg = dk.config.parse_config('~/mydonkey/' + args['--config'] + '.ini')
  File "/home/pi/donkey/donkey/config.py", line 27, in parse_config
    vehicle = config['vehicle']
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/configparser.py", line 937, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'vehicle'